# multiple android developer accounts with one google account

Tags: android

I wish to create multiple android developer accounts with one google account so that 'ownership' is with one google account. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

As per google policies Multiple google play accounts are not allowed. If google found multiple accounts with same name they will ban all of your accounts.

Also this is not a good idea of having multiple accounts on same name. If one of your account suspended all of your accounts will be suspended. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4454563?hl=en